# Gulp, bundle is not a function

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm new in gulp and i want to write task with browserify. That's my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify'); 
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');



gulp.task("browserify", function () {
  return browserify('src/js/main/main.js').bundle().pipe(source('main.js')).pipe(gulp.det(dest+'js'));
})
```

And i have error:

> TypeError: browserify(...).bundle is not a function

Comment: Have you checked the API docs? Is `bundle` a method of `browserify`? This isn't a gulp error fyi.

Comment: Seems you need [prebundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify#prebundle) or [postbundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify#postbundle)

Comment: I solve this problem. I should use var browserify = require('browserify'); instead var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

Comment: You should also use [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) instead of [gulp-browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify) which is no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

OP solved this issue by using

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
```

instead of

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify')
```